# WPF Update Source Trigger Implementation

Tags: wpf, data-binding, updatesourcetrigger

I have a custom object Foo with a boolean property called Flagged and when someone successfully types something in a text box it changes flagged to true and updates another textblock on the screen with some text.  The problem is I can get it to work on loading the initial data but nothing happens when the user successfully types something in to flip the flag.

I have to do the majority of this in code behind and I have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on my object Foo.  What is wrong with my code below?

Thanks.

```
private Border CreateNewBorder()
    {
        Border b = new Border();
        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

        b.Style = (Style)this.FindResource("myBorder");
        tb.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, CreateBinding());
        b.Child = tb;

        return b;
    }

    private Binding CreateBinding()
    {
        Binding bind = new Binding();
        bind.Source = Foo;
        bind.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        bind.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        bind.Path = new PropertyPath("Flagged");
        bind.Converter = new BoolToStringConverter();

        return bind;
    }
```

Comment: Have you verified in the debugger that Flagged is set to true when the user types?  Is the Foo object used as the Source in CreateBinding() the same instance as is being updated when the user types?  Can you post the relevant bits of the Foo code?

Comment: Also note there is no point setting an UpdateSourceTrigger (or Mode=TwoWay) on a TextBlock.Text binding -- the user can't type into a TextBlock so there will never be any updates to push back to the binding source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're probably just missing change notifications on Foo. Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on Foo and called the PropertyChanged event from the Flagged setter?